# Writing a C# Asp.net MVC 4 Json Parser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp.net mvc 4 framework. I want code to parse json received from view using jquery to array list. My json is this:

```
"{\"ServiceDataModel\":[{\"ServiceId\":\"7\",\"ServiceName\":\"Test Service\",\"ServiceRate\":\"4\",\"NoOfTimes\":\"1\",\"TotalAmount\":\"4\",\"Discount\":\"1\",\"NetAmount\":\"3\"},
{\"ServiceId\":\"7\",\"ServiceName\":\"Test Service\",\"ServiceRate\":\"36\",\"NoOfTimes\":\"1\",\"TotalAmount\":\"36\",\"Discount\":\"2\",\"NetAmount\":\"34\"}]}"
```

I am not sure that this is correct json or not? I am receiving this in controller during debugging.

And this is my code:

```
public ActionResult SavePatientServices(string id, string totalnetamount, string remarks, string approvedby)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string test = Regex.Unescape(id);

        ServiceDataModel datum = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceDataModel>(id);
        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(id);

       var log = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceDataModel>(id);
       var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServiceDataModel>>(stuff);
        //List<ServiceDataModel> ListAnswers = serializer.Deserialize<List<ServiceDataModel>>(stuff);
        return Content("");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error messages are you getting?

If your JSON is going to rather static, I suggest you use online tools like [JSON2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert this text to populated objects.

Once you've done that, you can use JSON.NET to deserialize this text using commands like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about parsing|serialise , You can easily send list of objects as a json.

### MVC Action :

Send your object like this it ill automatically handle as a json. Dont worry about serialise.

```
public JsonResult GetUsersData()  
        {  
         var usersList = new List<UserModel>  
            {  
                new UserModel  
                {  
                    UserId = 1,  
                    UserName = "Ram",  
                    Company = "Mindfire Solutions"  
                },  
                new UserModel  
                {  
                    UserId = 1,  
                    UserName = "chand",  
                    Company = "Mindfire Solutions"  
                },  
                new UserModel  
                {  
                    UserId = 1,  
                    UserName = "Abc",  
                    Company = "Abc Solutions"  
                }  
            };        

            return Json(usersList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }
```

### Ajax :

Ajax have default parse for XML and Json. Dont worry about parsing.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    url:"", 
    success: function (data) {      
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {      
    }
});
```